How to programmatically retrieve a permission's icon on Android OS
This thread addressed this issue:
How to get the icon for an Android permission?
However I don't see in it the ultimate solution.  The code that is in this thread always returns 'o' for the icon and UNKNOWN for the group in order to get the icon.
I know it must still be possible as I see other Android applications "phone, contacts" displaying the icon.  Also when I request a permission there is an icon in the alertDialog.  Just don't know how to resolve it.
Anyone else trying to do this?
RLB
I've tried the examples in code and other ways to retrieve icons from other activities but for permissions I can't get it to work or figure out how to get the drawable resource.

"I know it must still be possible as I see other Android applications "phone, contacts" displaying the icon" -- you see them displaying an icon. Do you have evidence that they are getting some platform-supplied icon, versus using one of their own? "Also when I request a permission there is an icon in the alertDialog" -- that dialog itself comes from privileged platform code, not a third-party app.

It's probably no longer possible since I can't find any third-party apps that show the icons.  I guess if I want to do it I'd have to add my own icons.  Not a big deal but I thought some system resources would be available and I just didn't know how to access them.
